# Win GUI App started from Console => print to console impossible?

Tags: winapi, console-application

this is not yet another "I need a console in my GUI app" that has been discussed quite frequently. My situation differs from that.

I have a Windows GUI application, that is run from a command line. Now if you pass wrong parameters to this application, I do *not* want a popup to appear stating the possible switches, but I want that printed into the console that spawned my process.

I got that far that I can print into the console (call to AttachConsole(...) for parent process) but the problem is my application is not "blocking". As soon as I start it, the command prompt returns, and all output is written into this window (see attached image for illustration).

[image: _]

I played around a bit, created a console app, ran it, and see there, it "blocks", the prompt only re-appears after the app has terminated. Switching my GUI app to /SUBSYSTEM:Console causes strange errors (MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: nonresolved external Symbol "_main" in function "___tmainCRTStartup".)

I have seen the pipe approach with an ".exe" and a ".com" file approach from MSDEV but I find it horrible. Is there a way to solve this prettier?

Comment: Changing to a console subsystem sounds like the right way to go about it. You'll have to change your main declaration to be consistent with a console application though. Other than that AFAIK you wouldn't be able to have it block using a WinMain since the command line is just launching it.

Comment: Switching to a console subsystem has other side effects. If launched from a shortcut instead of a console window, it will create a new console, even if the shortcut provided the correct parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This is not behaviour that you can change by modifying your application (aside from re-labelling it as already discussed).  The command interpreter looks at the subsystem that an executable is labelled with, and decides whether to wait for the application to terminate accordingly.  [If the executable is labelled as having a GUI, then the command interpreter doesn't wait for it to terminate.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120)

In some command interpreters this is configurable.   In [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html), for example, one can [configure the command interpreter to always wait for applications to terminate](http://jpsoft.com./help/waiting.htm), even GUI ones.  In Microsoft's CMD, this is not configurable behaviour, however.  The Microsoft answer is to use the [`START` command](http://microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx) with the `/WAIT` option.

Once again: This is not the behaviour of *your* application.  There is, apart from relabelling as a TUI program, no programmatic way involving *your* code to change this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe write a console-based wrapper app that checks the parameters, prints the error message on bad parameters, and calls/starts up the actual program when the parameters are correct?

Comment: That's what i tried avoiding :( the MSDEV solution mentioned up there has exactly such a ".com" file wrapper app, that is prioritized in the windows console, so when you type "myapp" [return] it will first attempt to start "myapp.com" and then "myapp.exe" but this is a standalone app and I do not want to distribute multiple files. The solution should be contained in a single individual app to make sure it doesnt break when someone forgets to drag along both parts.